# Paypal sandbox return url is not getting the response from paypal

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am working on localhost and testing payment for paypal sandbox. But I am not able to get the response from paypal.

Thanks

Comment: not surprised, unless you open up your localhost to the internet

Answer (score 0):

### Actual Testing of PayPal IPN

In order for PayPal to send an Instant Payment Notification, you must provide them (either as a parameter on the purchase/transaction, or as part of your IPN Settings under the account being paid) a URL which they can notify. This URL must be accessible from the internet, so is preferably hosted on a publicly accessible server, and with an address like http://www.yourserver.com/paypalIPN.php

Hosting an IPN listener on a server which is not accessible from the public internet, like under "localhost" on your own computer, will be impossible for the PayPal servers to contact, and so no IPN messages will be recieved.

### Callback to PayPal to Confirm IPN

If you are getting the PayPal IPN requests (they will normally be a POST request with a number of parameters), but you are having trouble calling PayPal back to confirm the transaction details, then this suggests that your server is having trouble making calls out to the internet.

This may be due to a configuration issue in your Webserver software, a firewall issue on the server, or a network issue. The first check would be to create a PHP file and attempt to use cURL or `file_get_contents()` to call and return a webpage, like Google's main page. If these calls work, then it may be a configuration issue specific to your IPN Handler.

There are a number of Open Source IPN Handlers available, which makes deploying a PayPal-backed payment system much easier. Just jump on Google and have a look around.